# CSS styles doesn't work in menu toolbar in Firefox (extension)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

If I put my extension in menu bar, after closing extension some CSS properties doesn't work. (In the add-on toolbar it works perfectly)

Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iM9EVFe8M4U

github: https://github.com/Exclumice/firex/tree/master/content

CSS: https://github.com/Exclumice/firex/blob/master/skin/overlay.css

CSS properties which become inoperable:

```
.proxy-help {
    background: url("icon-help.png");
    background-position: 97% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.proxy-help-text > label {
    width: 80%;
}
.proxy-list hbox > label.proxy-country {
    padding: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    background: url("planet.png");
    background-position: 5px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 180px;
    text-indent: 25px;
}
.proxy-list .proxy-type {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

How to fix it? Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let's chat about it here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56501/css-styles-doesnt-work-in-menu-toolbar-in-firefox-extension

Comment: Hey man I see you're getting no reply. I say try redoing your css without percentages. Use box styling only.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after testing we find this.

When it is in toolbar, the elements are black in DOM Inspector, so they are NOT anonymous:
[image: in toolbar - non anon]

But when we move them to `PanelUI-popup` they become anonymous, notice how they are red in the inspector:
[image: in panelui-popup now are anonymous]

maybe @nmaier can advise here.

I'm thinking a box loses its box'ness so then the % widths you used are taking the % of osme different box once placed in panelui-poup.